# Calling a stored procedure within an IF statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Does anybody know if this is allowed?

```
IF CALL GET_RIGHT_NODE(edge) = 15
THEN
SELECT "IT WORKS";
```

I'm getting an error on this syntax, is it possible any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return values from stored procedures should be captured in OUT paramters (whereas those from user defined functions can be captured as `@returnValue = function()`).

So, your `GET_RIGHT_NODE` should take an OUT parameter and set it to the return value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_RIGHT_NODE
(
     @edge INT,
     @returnValue INT OUTPUT
)
AS

-- Definition of the proc.
```

then you would call the procedure as follows:

```
DECLARE @returnValue INT

CALL GET_RIGHT_NODE(@edge, @returnValue)

IF (@returnValue = 15)
THEN
    SELECT 'IT WORKS'
```